# Not able to login to the remote RHEL server

Tags: ssh, git

**Problem**: Not able to login to remote server using SSH.

**Environment**: Windows 7 PC, Connecting server using Git Bash terminal
Below is the command I use to login.

```
ssh myUserName@hostname.extention
```

and I also tried to login with IP Address.

```
ssh myUserName@10.234.167.234
```

I am not getting any response/messages in Terminal. The terminal just return in the path.

```
USER@HOST XXXX /c/Users/USER/
$ssh myUserName@10.234.167.234

USER@HOST XXXX /c/Users/USER/
$
```

> What Would be the reson?
>
> How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please try "ssh -v user@server" and report back what it says.

Comment: Check the logs on the server to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ssh config client file and see if you mentioned any user there or you are using system user, it should match to remote user, another thing is check if remote server only allow key based authentication and password based denied.